# Angular2 login form doesn't catch password

Tags: angular, components

I am creating and Angular2 login form but I have problems because the component is not catching the password...

This is the view:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>
        <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="user.email" required />
        <span *ngIf="!email.valid">El email es obligatorio</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="user.password" required />
        <span *ngIf="!password.valid">La contraseña es obligatoria</span>
    </p>

    <button (click)="onSubmit()" > Entrar </button>
```

And this is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';


import {User}         from '../model/user';
import {LoginService}  from '../services/login.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
})

// Clase del componente donde irán los datos y funcionalidades
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    public tituloLogin: string = "Identificate";
    public user;

constructor(
        private _loginService: LoginService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router
    ){} 

    ngOnInit(){

        this.user = {
            "email": "",
            "password": "",
            "gethash": "false"
        };

    }

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.user); 
}
    }
```

The system catch correctly the email with the model but not the password...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see at first glance is to try changing:

`public user;`

to

```
public user: User = {
            "email": "",
            "password": "",
            "gethash": "false"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some problem with your validation, which threw an error, which affected the value. This I noticed when I tested your code.

Since you don't technically have a form, you cannot use things like `!email.valid`, since there is no such thing. If you only want to use two-way binding and actually not utilize form, this should do it, change your validations to:

```
<span *ngIf="!user.email">El email es obligatorio</span>
<span *ngIf="!user.password">La contraseña es obligatoria</span>
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aO5xp580CTXJHYzYw9n7?p=preview)

But if you want to use a form, make the following changes:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)">
<p>
    <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" required />
    <span *ngIf="!email?.valid">El email es obligatorio</span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" #password="ngModel" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" required />
    <span *ngIf="!password?.valid">La contraseña es obligatoria</span>
</p>
  <button type="submit"> Entrar </button>
</form>
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FsmWjN3KKUJtPnGyVAPw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

I had changed as follows:

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-md-4">
    <p>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" #username="ngModel" required />
        <span *ngIf="!username.valid">El nombre de usuario es obligatorio</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" #password="ngModel" required />
        <span *ngIf="!password.valid">La contraseña es obligatoria</span>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

Is not allowed to use anymor ngForm and ngModel in this way:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-md-4">
```

so for now, the corect way to user forms is the first one.

thanks!